# TypeError: Network request failed fetch in react native

Tags: react-native, get, fetch

Iam trying to get data from url but getting this error "Network request failed", the URL is working correctly in postman, here is the output of postman

[image]

my code:

```
  const getCategories = async () => {
try {
  const url = "*******/api/categories/getRandomCategories/4"
  await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
  }).then((res) => console.log(res.json()))
    .then((resJson) => {
      console.log(resJson)
    }).catch((e) => console.log(e))
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)

}
```

}

Comment: `http` or `https`, is it Android or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

We can't test your API endpoint because you do not provide it. You should try to see if an other endpoint is working properly with your code, you can use [a random one for example](https://random-data-api.com/).

Also your code is a bit messy, you are returning a `console.log` instead of your response as json in the first `then`. Try to simplify it like this:

```js
const getCategories = async () => {
   try {
     const url = "..."
     const response = await fetch(url, {
       method: 'GET'
     })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(responseJson => console.log(responseJson))
   } 
   catch (error) {
     console.log(error)
   }
}
```

Since you get a `Network request failed` you should verify that your url is the same as the one you use in Postman, e.g. if you use a base url constant make sure it is correct:

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://yourdomain.com' // Be sure there is no "/" at the end.
const url = baseUrl + '/api/categories/getRandomCategories/4'
```

Finally you should verify you use the correct headers to when fetching.